# Imagemagick cmd line Pdf to jpg perfect but php results different

Tags: php, imagemagick

so when I run this on my mac

convert shipfittest.pdf[0] -profile /Adobe/CMYK/USWebCoatedSWOP.icc -profile /rgb/sRGB.icc test1.jpg

I get color perfect conversion of pdf first page to jpg.

What's the equivalent use of profiles with php?
For example:

```
 $im = new \Imagick();
 $im->profileImage('icc', [CMYK icc profile);
 $im->readimage($assetFilePath . '[0]'); // reads first page '[0]'
```

Where / how do you set the second profile for the output file?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't call `Imagick::profileImage()` multiple times? Documentation says it's additive.

Comment: THanks miken32. I verify the pdf is CMYK colorspace which is true but when i add another icc sRGB profile i get ColorspaceColorProfileMismatch `icc' @ error/profile.c/ProfileImage/887 
I thought i was missing something in the flow or assignment. CMD line is perfect but not an option for the app

Comment: Sorted with using multiple profiles.